# $||u||_2= \sup_{x \in K} |u(x)|$ is not a norm when $K$ is closed subset of $\mathbb R^k$ and $u(x)$ is a continuous function on $K$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification, normed-spaces

$K \subset \mathbb R^n$  and  $K$ is closed.  $C(K)$  is the set of all continuous function form $K$  to $\mathbb R$.

Now for every $u(x) \in C(K)$   , $||u||_2= \sup_{x \in K} |u(x)|$.

$||u||_2$ is not a norm function as $||u||_2$ will not be defined for many elements of $C(K)$.

E.g. $[0 , \infty)$  is a closed subset of $\mathbb R$.

Now the function $f(x) = x^2$  is a continuous function on $\mathbb R$ and unbounded above.

Have I gone wrong anywhere ? Can anyone please check my solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Your solution seems perfectly OK. You correctly identified the problem, which is that the supremum value is not defined for all elements of $C(K)$.

The only minor correction (which is more or less semantic) I would make is to say that the function $f(x)=x^2$ is a continuous function on $[0, \infty)$. Sure, it is also continuous on $\mathbb R$, but in your case, you want to show that it is an element of $C(K)$, and $K$, in this case, is $[0,\infty)$.

Note that if $K$ were a compact, and not just a closed, set, then your counterexample would no longer work. Nor would any other, because if $K$ is compact, then the defined mapping **is** a norm on $C(K)$.